# Understanding block offset bits in caching

Tags: caching, memory, block

I've been reading the chapter about cache memory in "Computer System: A Programmer's Perspective" by Bryant and O'Hallaron, and there's something I'm having trouble understanding about the block offset bits. Here's a snapshot from the book:[image]

In this example they're assuming words are 4 bytes long, it's a direct mapping and each line consists 8 bytes. They're using 3 bits in order to decide the offset from the left-most cell, so from my understanding if block offset was 010, cache would've returned the data from w2 to w5. But I don't understand what would've happened if block offset was 100, there's no 8th cell in the block, so we can't return a 4 byte word starting at w5, so it would make more sense using only 2 bits for block offset. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're right.

> Can't return a 4 byte word starting at w5.

But the diagram has bits 100 in binary -> 2^2 -> w4. So you start at w4. count up to w7 and you get 4 bytes aka a word which constitutes bytes from w_4,w_5,w_6,w_7.